# Why am i not getting values from visualforce page on my controller?

Tags: parameters, controller, visualforce, commandbutton

when I try to get the selected values from picklist and the inputText value by clicking the command button, it's not really passing them to my controller.

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="FieldsAndTypesPicklists" >
<apex:form >

    <apex:inputText value="{!newDatasetName}" />
    <apex:outputlabel value="Product type: "/>   

    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedTypeProd}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypesProduct}"/>
    </apex:selectList>

    <apex:commandButton value="Add new values" action="{!SaveValues}"  />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class FieldsAndTypesPicklists {

    public String selectedTypeProd {get; set;}

    public String newDatasetName { get; set; }

    public void SaveValues() {
        System.debug('>>> InputText value: '+newDatasetName);
    }

     public Set<SelectOption> getTypesProduct(){

        System.debug('>>> Select Type value: '+selectedTypeProd);
        Set<SelectOption> typesProd = new Set<SelectOption>();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistEntryList = OpportunityLineItem.TypeProduct__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();

        for(Schema.PicklistEntry plEntry : picklistEntryList){
            String typeProduct = string.ValueOf(plEntry.getValue());
            typesProd.add(new SelectOption(typeProduct, typeProduct));
        }

        return typesProd;
    }  

 }
```

I've made the corresponding debugs to see the inputText and the picklist selected value.

1. selectedTypeProd is **null**
2. it is not executing the method SaveValues()

If I take out the piece of code where is the selected list (on the VF) and the **getTypesProduct()** method in the controller it works fine for the inputText value. It seems like the other part is affecting the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make TypesProduct as a set of strings. So it will works.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue and got it working by adding `multiselect="false"`

Change your code from

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedTypeProd}" size="1">
```

to

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedTypeProd}" size="1" multiselect="false">
```